# Java PIT classpath issue

Tags: java, pitest

I am having a folder "mutant" which contains a text file with just a single line called `java.utils.Collection`. I have generated test cases using Randoop and saved them in the same folder. The test cases have names RegressionTest*.java
I am trying to run PIT now to generate mutants. The command that I am typing as per http://pitest.org/quickstart/commandline/ is the following---

```
    java -cp C:\Users\happy\OneDrive\Desktop\pitest-1.4.3.jar;C:\Users\happy\OneDrive\Desktop\pitest-command-line-1.4.3.jar;C:\Users\happy\OneDrive\Desktop\pitest-entry-1.4.3.jar;C:\Users\happy\OneDrive\Desktop\junit-4.10.jar;C:\Users\happy\OneDrive\Desktop\testng-6.8.5.jar 

org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport 
--reportDir C:\Users\happy\OneDrive\Desktop\report 
--targetClasses myclasses.* 
--targetTests mutant.Regression* 
--sourceDirs C:\Users\happy\OneDrive\Desktop\mutant
```

and the error I am getting is `Exception in thread "main". org.Pitest.help.PitHelpError: No mutations found. This probably means there is an issue with either the supplied classpath or filters`

I believe that problem is associated with targetClasses. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`Collection` is in `java.util`, not java.util**s**.

You can check that there is indeed generated tests.

Furthermore, I think the tested code you want Pitest to mutate should have it's source code indicated by **--sourceDirs**.